# using the classicthesis package , can't add the bibliography (reference)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, classicthesis

i got `\include{FrontBackMatter/Bibliography}` in my main.tex file 
and in the Bibliography.tex it got

```
\label{app:bibliography} % Reference the bibliography elsewhere with \autoref{app:bibliography}

\manualmark % Work-around to have small caps also here in the headline
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\bibname}} % Work-around to have small caps also
%\phantomsection
\refstepcounter{dummy}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{\beforebibskip}} % Place the bibliography slightly below the rest of the document content in the table of contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocEntry{\bibname}}

\printbibliography
```

this but i can't add the reference to my main.pdf or it's being printed

Comment: Did you press the special bibliography-button?

Comment: You haven't shown a full code example (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), so we can only guess. But from what I have seen so far (`\printbibliography`), you will have to run Biber on your file, so that the compilation sequence becomes LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" is your favourite LaTeX flavour: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for background explanations and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help on getting your editor to run Biber for you.

Comment: @Quintis you're using several years old classicthesis template; you better download the newest version https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/wiki/Home

Comment: Any news here? Did you manage to obtain the desired bibliography? As the question stands now, my best guess is that you didn't run Biber as required. In that case your question would essentially be a duplicate of one of the two questions I linked above. If there is no new development here in due time, I will vote to close.